# Spring Boot Jpa: Can I configure a JSON file as Database?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

**I want to do CRUD operations on JSON file with JPA Repository.**

I tried with JSON Populators as [described by Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-repository-populators).

But it is giving me `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'`.

Is there any other way I can do JPA operations without specifying any database with just on Json File?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried JSON Populators, custom implementation of JPA methods, excluding  {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class}, tried with class field in json [{"_class":"com.customer.model.Customer","customerId":2,"firstName":"Rahul"}]

Comment: you should add some code in your question

Comment: I would but I wanted to be sure that this thing is even possible or not? Can we configure a file as datasource in JPA and do operations on them?

Comment: Unless there is a JDBC driver that allows using JSON as a datasource no there isn't a way to use JPA over a JSON file. JPA is tied to JDBC. The "tutorial"  you are following isn't for using JSON as JPA, it is using JSON to fill a database (the name populator should give that away).

Comment: Add a more detailed message of exception reason should be better described there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any Other way I can do JPA operation without specifying any database with just on Json File?

No.
JPA claims to be data source agnostic, but the only relevant implementations that actually exists are for relational databases only.

Repository populators are tools to load data from a resource and then use a repository to write them to a database.
They are typically used to initialise databases.
You can use different repositories (JPA, Mongo ...) to write to different types of database.

You could write your own Spring Data module reading and writing data to and from a JSON file, but no such implementation currently esxists as far as I know and it is probably not worth the effort for almost all scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Now if you're using Java, there is none, but if you're using Javascript, you can use [lowdb](https://github.com/typicode/lowdb), a JSON database.

Comment: I am using Java.

Comment: spring boot added js support?